# Как реализовать решение задачи ЕГЭ на C++?

Tags: c++, pascal

Возник такой вопрос: как реализовать решение следующей задачи на C++? Вводятся число N - количество строк. В каждой из N строк через пробел вводятся 4 значения: название АЗС (не более 20 символов), название улицы (не более 20 символов), марка бензина (92, 95, 98), цена за бензин этой марки (число от 1000 до 3000). Программа должна выводить три числа через пробел - количество АЗС, на которых бензин каждой марки продаётся дешевле всего. На Паскале решение этой задачи выглядит так:

```
var min, ans: array[92..98] of integer; // Массивы для минимальной цены и для количества АЗС
    c: char; // "Мусорная" переменная для ввода названия АЗС и улицы
    i, k, N, b: integer;

begin

   for i:=92 to 98 do begin // Заполнение массивов
      min[i]:=3001; // Максимальная цена за бензин = 3000, поэтому заполняем массив 3001
      ans[i]:=0; // Счётчик количества АЗС
   end;

   readln(N); // Ввод количества АЗС

   for i:=1 to N do begin

      repeat // Ввод названия АЗС до тех пор, пока не будет введён пробел
         read(c);
      until c=' ';

      repeat // Ввод улицы до тех пор, пока не будет введён пробел
         read(c);
      until c = ' ';

      readln(k, b); // Ввод марки бензина и его цены

      if b<min[k] then begin // Если цена меньше минимума за эту марку
         min[k] := b; // Минимум = цена
         ans[k] := 1; //  Количество АЗС = 1
      end else if min[k] = b then // Если минимум = цене
         ans[k] := ans[k] + 1; // Количество АЗС +1
   end;

   writeln (ans[92], ' ', ans[95], ' ', ans[98]); // Вывод количеств АЗС с наиболее низкими ценами каждой марки

end.
```

Суть в том, что название АЗС и название улицы для ответа по сути не нужны. В связи с этим логичнее было бы записывать их в отдельную переменную, которая с каждой новой введённой буквой будет перезаписываться, до тех пор, пока не будет введён пробел (пробел = конец ввода слова). Попытался сделать так же на C++, но понял, что `cin >>` не учитывает пробелы. Потом попытался сделать то же самое с `cin.get()`, но столкнулся с проблемой, что он учитывает ещё и символ новой строки и поэтому работает неправильно. `cin.getline()` на сколько я понял работает только со строками, и поэтому с переменной это сделать не получится. Подскажите, как вообще можно реализовать решение этой задачи на C++, желательно используя переменную для лишней информации, а не строку (хотелось бы, чтобы программа занимала как можно меньше памяти). Спасибо.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что преподаватель примет подобное решение: здесь нет, по сути, логики обработки информации в том виде, как она описана в задаче. Вместо обработки строк реализована фильтрация ввода с отбрасыванием ненужной для достижения узкой конкретной цели информации. Причем информация просто выбрасывается. Дальше, если бы вдруг понадобилось, с ней работать не выйдет: ее просто нет. Конечно, лучше  такие вещи спросить у преподавателя, чем здесь, поскольку я, естественно, играю в угадайку. Но мне кажется, преподаватель вряд ли ожидал увидеть фильтр ввода. (продолжу вторым комментом)

Comment: Как мне кажется из постановки задачи, преподаватель ожидал увидеть обработку строк с разделением их на слова, преобразование цифровой части строки в число (цена), сохранение этих данных в структуре описания АЗС. Сами АЗС могли бы храниться в массиве, а формирование запрошенных данных предполагало бы обход и обработку массива структур. Но еще раз повторю: с моей стороны это просто угадайка, и нужно уточнять у преподавателя. Если преподаватель будет доволен таким ответом, тогда мои извинения ТС, но грош цена такому преподавателю.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Дело в том, что вышеупомянутое решение предложил сам составитель этого задания. В процессе работы программа должна занимать как можно меньше памяти, и её время работы должно быть минимальным (одни из критериев оценки). Тем более в условии задачи не говорится о дальнейшей работе с этими строками. Поэтому лучше всего было бы просто выкинуть ненужную для ответа информацию. Мне же просто интересно, как реализовать перезапись переменной для ненужной информации на C++ до тех пор, пока не будет введён пробел.

Comment: Ясно. Тогда еще раз приношу Вам свои извинения. Что касается задачи... Я бы в цикле читал символы, проверяя, не являются ли они цифрой с помощью isdigit. Как только попалась цифра - вернул ее в поток с помощью putback и прочитал уже целиком число

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Спасибо. Ещё такой вопрос: правильно ли я понял, что putback() возвращает последний введённый с клавиатуры символ и записывает его назад в переменную:
cin >> ch;
cin.putback(ch);
cin >> ch; ?

Comment: Давно не сталкивался с потоками ввода-вывода... Если правильно помню, она возвращает в поток ввода тот символ, который Вы ей передали, и при последующем чтении из потока именно этот символ прочитается первым. Я предлагаю использовать эту функцию для того, чтобы не потерять первую цифру вводимого числа, которую мы читаем при проверке с помощью isdigit

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

/*
 * Вводятся число N - количество строк.
 * В каждой из N строк через пробел вводятся 4 значения:
 * название АЗС (не более 20 символов),
 * название улицы (не более 20 символов),
 * марка бензина (92, 95, 98),
 * цена за бензин этой марки (число от 1000 до 3000).
 *
 * Программа должна выводить три числа через пробел -
 * количество АЗС, на которых бензин каждой марки продаётся дешевле всего.
 */

using namespace std;

struct GasStation{
    char* stationName = new char[20];
    char* streetName = new char[20];
    int mark;
    int price;

public: GasStation(char* _stationName, char* _streetName, int _mark, int _price){
        stationName = _stationName;
        streetName = _streetName;
        if (_mark == 92 || _mark == 95 || _mark == 98)
            mark = _mark;

        if (_price >= 1000 && _price <= 3000)
            price = _price;
    }

};


struct MinPriceCount{
    int minPrice92 = 0;
    int minPrice95 = 0;
    int minPrice98 = 0;

public: MinPriceCount(int min92, int min95, int min98){
        minPrice92 = min92;
        minPrice95 = min95;
        minPrice98 = min98;
    }
};

MinPriceCount searchMinPrice(int amount);
void printMinPrice(MinPriceCount minPr);


int main() {
    cout << "Enter amount gas station: ";
    int amount;
    cin >> amount;
    printMinPrice(searchMinPrice(amount));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

MinPriceCount searchMinPrice(int amount){
    char* stationName = new char[20];
    char* streetName = new char[20];
    int mark;
    int price;

    int minPrice92 = 3000;
    int minPrice95 = 3000;
    int minPrice98 = 3000;

    int countMinPrice92 = 0;
    int countMinPrice95 = 0;
    int countMinPrice98 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {

        cout << "Enter name of gas station, street, mark and price: ";
        cin >> stationName >> streetName >> mark >> price;
        GasStation gasStation(stationName, streetName, mark, price);

        if (gasStation.mark == 92 && gasStation.price < minPrice92){
            minPrice92 = gasStation.price;
            countMinPrice92 = 1;
        }

        else if (gasStation.mark == 92 && gasStation.price == minPrice92)
            countMinPrice92++;

        if (gasStation.mark == 95 && gasStation.price < minPrice95){
            minPrice95 = gasStation.price;
            countMinPrice95 = 1;
        }

        else if (gasStation.mark == 95 && gasStation.price == minPrice95)
            countMinPrice95++;

        if (gasStation.mark == 98 && gasStation.price < minPrice98){
            minPrice98 = gasStation.price;
            countMinPrice98 = 1;
        }

        else if (gasStation.mark == 98 && gasStation.price == minPrice98)
            countMinPrice98++;
    }
    MinPriceCount minPrice(countMinPrice92, countMinPrice95, countMinPrice98);

    return minPrice;
}

void printMinPrice(MinPriceCount minPr){
    cout << minPr.minPrice92 << " " << minPr.minPrice95 << " " << minPr.minPrice98 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `stationName = _stationName` а вы уверены?)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, разрешается ли на ЕГЭ С++11

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    size_t n;
    cin >> n;

    array<int, 3> ms = {92, 95, 98};
    map<int, int> min_p, ans;

    transform(ms.begin(), ms.end(), inserter(min_p, min_p.end()),
        [](int m){ return make_pair(m, numeric_limits<int>::max()); });
    transform(ms.begin(), ms.end(), inserter(ans, ans.end()),
        [](int m){ return make_pair(m, 0); });

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        string nil;
        int m, p;
        cin >> nil >> nil >> m >> p;

        if(p < min_p[m]){
            min_p[m] = p;
            ans[m] = 1;
        } else if(p == min_p[m]){
            ++ans[m];
        }
    }

    for(auto& pair: ans){
        cout << pair.second << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```